# form with inline onsubmit is not fired from iframe

Tags: javascript, submit, onsubmit

I have a form with a inline onsubmit event (that sends a simple alert for testing purposes). That alert fires OK when submiting information from this page.

This form has an iframe which have a button that takes the form parent, and submits it. The "postback" on the parent is firing OK but the alert not.
Maybe I'm doing something wrong because the alert is not firing or it cannot be possible?

Parent Form:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="mipagina.aspx" 
onsubmit="javascript:alert('hola');" id="form1">
```

Iframe JS:

```
formulario = window.parent.document.forms.item(0);
formulario.submit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the normal behavior. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit):

> The HTMLFormElement.submit() method submits a given .
>
> This method is similar, but not identical to, activating a form's submit . When invoking this method directly, however:
>
> **No submit event is raised**. In particular, the form's onsubmit event handler is not run.
> Constraint validation is not triggered.

The only workaround I may see is:

- add your code before **formulario.submit();**
- very bad idea: overwrite **document.getElementById('form1').submit** method (please avoid this)